# Javascript/ Jquery slide menu not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've been working on a website and when testing it out on a VM the slide menu didn't work. I've since managed to replicate the error in newer versions of Chrome The page is 
http://paperfromabc2xyz.co.uk/

When you shrink the screen size small enough to loose the main menu you'll get a NAV Burger icon. Clicking this *should* slide a menu in. The Javascript file is 'App.JS'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click does not get caught, somehow because the span does not have dimensions (the `:before` element does not expand it).

Add this to your styles:

```
span.Burger{ display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick but does add long white bar to top of page and bring left and right side bars up to top of page...

Comment: @Thomh Sorry, I don't see what you are referring to? For me, on Chrome and Firefox, the page is identical, the only difference is that it works. (No white bar, and the scroll bar was already taking up the whole page height).

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Fixed it with a couple of extra line of CSS. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it

Comment: Are you not getting the white bar above the header?

Comment: @Thomh oh, ok, when you re-expand the window, now I see it. Just remove `#Header{ margin-top: 10px; }` ?

Comment: I opted to bring the side ads down by 10 and get rid of the margin. ah well, whole other story. Just got thrown when you said you couldn't see it :P Thanks again, that one's been bugging me!

Answer (score 0):

for a start use a library as Jquery to simplify your code; then put your javascript code in an `$(document).ready(function () {}` then  then add to your css : `span.Burger{ display: inline-block; }`

Comment: He is already using jQuery and `$(document).ready()` for this. http://paperfromabc2xyz.co.uk/app.js

Comment: Sorry, dude Blexy already called the display CSS. I'm al;ready loading jQuery and document ready :S

Comment: Yes sorry didn't look carefully but, anyway $(document).ready() needs to be placed at te beginning of the code.